# CSS on chrome behaves differently on firefox when resizing buttons

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, button, resize

I am new to JS and using a tic tac toe game as a learning tool.
http://publisher.evidon.com/edpractice/tictactoe.html

This is what I thought was nearly finished, until I opened it up on firefox.
None of the positions or button sizes are being applied on firefox, but look great on chrome. Any advice?

Here is a sample of the CSS I used:

```
input[type = button]
{
height: 166px;
width: 166px;
font-size : 0;
}

#button1{
position: absolute;
top : 91px;
left: 33px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: For starters, you don't have a doctype, so the page gets rendered in quirks mode. And different browsers have different quirks! So better fix that first. And the errors.

Comment: Thank you for that, I added a doc type. I am still experiencing the same issues though.

Comment: Do you have a "live" version of the page now? The page from the link in your question is still the quirks mode one.

Comment: oh sorry I did not get an email response for this. Yes I will upload it now at the same link above

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is. You should correct the other errors too though; they may cause problems later on. E.G. `onclick=showX("button1")` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a wrong filetype defined for the stylesheet in the `<link>` in your head.

Apparently, Chrome doesn't mind, but it does pose a problem for Firefox.

Solution: change the `type="text.css"` to the correct MIME type, `type="text/css"` (with a slash).

Comment: Thank you this worked! You have saved me a big  headache <3

Comment: OK. Can you mark this answer as correct, by clicking the check mark to the left. Then the question will no longer show up under the unsolved problems.